# How to store GeoJSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, asp.net-core, geojson

I'm trying to get a JSON formatted like GeoJSON with API. I get something for GET and can DELETE but when i try to post or put i get this error `System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument'`

Also I'm not getting exactly what I have in PostgreSQL. There is an extra `"rootElement"`

In PostgreSQL I have a table with columns `ID(integer)`,`type(string)`,`properties(json)`,`geometry(json)`. 
I insert this

```
{
"id": 1,
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [23.2,23]
},
"properties": {
    "name": "test2",
    "type": "testing"
}
}
```

And this is my class

```
public class Test
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public System.Text.Json.JsonDocument geometry { get; set; }

    public System.Text.Json.JsonDocument properties { get; set; }
}
```

What I get with GET is this

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "type": "test",
    "geometry": {
        "rootElement": {
            "type": "point",
            "coordinates": [
                23.2,
                23
            ]
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "rootElement": {
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "testing"
        }
    }
}
]
```

Comment: So you have an issue between the post and the get. Unfortunately you haven't provided any information about what you do between these steps... it is impossible to help you. Please edit your question and provide all the relevant information

Comment: @JGH I added some but I'm new to stackoverflow what  information should i provide ?